# How can I see all the output without a horizontal scrollbar appearing in Jupyter notebooks in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

For example (when running `print(dir())` or similar):

[image]

In this example the output is too long so the horizontal scrollbar appears.

But I want something like the following where there is wrapping instead of a scrollbar:

[image]

Is there a quick key to achieve it or some configuration?

Answer (score 1):

To get word wrapping in the output of a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code, put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"notebook.output.wordWrap": true,
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the output of `%lsmagic`, which doesn't put spaces after its commas. Does it only break on spaces?

Comment: @JohnY I reported a bug ticket: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/190086